# Modularização sem OSGI em projeto Web

Tags: tomcat

Tenho um projeto que será razoavelmente grande, então seria bem interessante modularizar, eu sei, existe o OSGi, mas eu achei muito complexo e tive dificuldade para adaptar a minha aplicação, a impressão que tive é que vai complicar mais do que facilitar a manutenção,é arrodeio demais simplesmente para usar uma classe que está em um jar separado através de uma interface, então estou pensando em fazer através de ClassLoader,  a estrutura que eu penso é a seguinte

Projeto Core

```
package core;

public interface IModulo {
<T> T getString();
}
```

Projeto Modulo exemplo

```
package modulo1;

import core.IModulo;

public class Teste implements IModulo{

public <T> T getString() {
    return (T) "Hello";
}
}
```

Projeto principal, onde será "instalado" os módulos, esse projeto principal já tem o projeto Core como dependência, ou seja, a interface IModulo já está no classpath, se eu executar através de um simples classe main, funciona, mas pelo Tomcat não, veja o trecho de código

```
  import core.IModulo;
   public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String jarDoModulo = "C:\\modulo1.jar";
        File file = new File(jarDoModulo);
        URL url;
        url = file.toURL();

        URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);          
        Class<IModulo> cls = (Class<IModulo>) cl.loadClass("modulo1.Teste");
        IModulo modulo1 = cls.newInstance();
        System.out.println(modulo1.getString());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

O erro que aparece é

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: core.IModulo
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 60 more
```

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, eu troquei a tag [tag:java-ee] pela [tag:tomcat] para tentar te ajudar a atrair mais respostas. Cada *container* possui suas especificidades de configuração de recursos e *ClassLoaders*. Além do que o Tomcat é um caso especial que não chega nem mesmo a ser um servidor de aplicação Java EE, é apenas um *container* Servlet / JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi seu requisito é basicamente separar implementações de determinadas interfaces do core. Estas implementações ficam em projetos `jar` à parte do seu projeto web principal.

O problema em que você esbarrou acontece pois o Tomcat possui sua própria hierarquia de [class loaders](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).

Da forma que seu código foi escrito, dentro do Tomcat o `IModulo` será administrado por um [`WebappClassLoader`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader.html) e a classe `Teste` pelo seu `URLClassLoader` (que não possuí nenhuma instância de `IModulo` carregada, logo, dispara uma exceção).

Existem dois caminhos recomendados aqui:

1. Coloque o `modulo1.jar` na pasta `WEB-INF/lib` do seu projeto principal. Dessa forma as classes do seu módulo estarão disponíveis para a aplicação e você não precisará nem mexer com *class loaders*. A modularidade ainda é mantida no sentido de ser possível trocar a implementação do módulo sem alterar a aplicação core.
2. Usar ou escrever um `ClassLoader` personalizado (se você realmente quer deixar seu módulo em um local *non-standard*). Até o Tomcat 7 você poderia usar um [VirtualWebappLoader](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/VirtualWebappLoader.html) para disponibilizar o jar do seu módulo; a partir do Tomcat 8 você pode usar o recurso de [PreResources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html#Nested_Components).

Comment: O problema da solução 1 é que eu teria que derrubar o tomcat e refazer o deploy para adicionar um modulo, com o classLoader penso eu, que eu posso "instalar" o jar em runtime e utilizá=lo em ter que parar o tomcat, estou certo?

Comment: Olá Rodrigo. Você não precisa derrubar o Tomcat, mas devido a própria natureza dos *class loaders*, precisará sim fazer um reload da aplicação. Configurar o Tomcat para ler novas versões de um .jar no `WEB-INF/lib` é questão de colocar um `reloadable="true"` no [context.xml](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html). Nesse processo ele "reabrirá" a aplicação (como se você tivesse dado um `touch` no `web.xml`) descartando o antigo `ClassLoader` e abrindo um novo com todos os recursos do seu novo jar.

Comment: Você ainda pode fazer uma cópia de toda a pasta da sua aplicação, substituir apenas o jar e fazer um [deploy paralelo](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) para evitar indisponibilidade para clientes consumindo versões antigas da aplicação.

Comment: Se mesmo um *reload* em ambiente versionado não atende seus requisitos eu diria para ir de OSGi mesmo. Substituição de classes a quente requer código não trivial (localizar todas as referências antigas de determinada classe, descartá-las, substituí-las por uma nova versão mantendo o estado das variáveis compatíveis, forçar GC do antigo `ClassLoader` para evitar *leaks*, etc).

Comment: Você vai acabar descobrindo que precisará demarcar interfaces de importação e exportação, de um *container* para gerir os *class loaders*, de comandos para publicar, startar e parar módulos, etc. No fim das contas acabará com um mini Equinox ou Felix escrito na unha :) (meu ponto é; se você realmente precisa fazer swap de *bundles* em produção à quente, OSGi acaba não sendo uma solução tão complexa assim, esse tipo de coisa realmente requer código complexo de infraestrutura).

Comment: Entendi Anthony, realmente acaba sendo um código complexo e OSGi deve não ficar tão complexo assim, bem, primeiramente eu estou organizando a infra do meu projeto, onde eu já realmente separo fisicamente os módulos, olha, incrivelmente o código do projeto ficou limpinho e muito fácil de entender, extender, testabilidade etc... impressionante a modularização o quanto facilita, no caso ele está "modularizado" mas não com hotdeploy, acredito que com calma, tentando aplicar o OSGi em cima da minha estrutura que fiz agora, a coisa fique mais clara.